# Why I have to use Cordova instead of phonegap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

For some reason I have to delete phonegap-1.4.1 and use cordova-1.5.0,
For this what I have did:
I have just removed the phonegap-1.4.1.jar and used cordova-1.5.0.jar.
(And also deleted and placed respective .js files.)

Upto this my task has been completed.... :)
But now I have one query what would be the benefit? (may be not now but for future),

I have read some links:
http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/

I am pasting one para:

**Over time, the PhoneGap distribution may contain additional tools that tie into other Adobe services, which would not be appropriate for an Apache project. For example, PhoneGap Build and Adobe Shadow together make a whole lot of strategic sense. PhoneGap will always remain free, open source software and will always be a free distribution of Apache Cordova.**

From the link come know:
http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/

**Currently, the only difference is in the name of the download package and will remain so for some time**
Still something is missing,
Let me know in short what is the benefit for moving phonegap to cordava(1.5.0 to 2.x any version). I need to change earlier used plugins??
For some version need to change:
https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins
Let me know if there anything specific for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget any blog or article before 2.0.0 - PhoneGap or Cordova, however you want to call the base libraries, has changed so much that all new plugins are totally incompatible with the interface of 1.x. If you need any plugin, check if it works with your version. Many plugins have been updated and are not maintained anymore for the old 1.x versions. For example, I'm doing exactly that for [the iOS/Android plugins that I maintain](https://github.com/AndiDog).

Other than that, there were lots of bugfixes since 1.4.0 came out, and support for new platforms was added. There is no good changelog page as far as I know, but you can check blogs like [Simon MacDonald's](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.de/search/label/phonegap) for some resources on what has changed.

Regarding PhoneGap Build, I can't give you any hints since I don't use it.